# Why Genymotion is not starting?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

This is the log file which i am getting.
However, in the error it prompted to open the virtual box and I tried. Its just didn't open.Tried whatsoever

This is the log:

```
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "hardware_opengl", "1")
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "hardware_opengl_disable_render", "0")
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Hardware acceleration is set from Guest Property
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual device configured
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560")
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtualization engine configured
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Trying to log in as "alpitanand20@gmail.com"
Jun 2 17:23:10 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual Machine status: off
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Start the device...
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "androvm_ip_management")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "--nic1", "hostonly")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "--hostonlyadapter1", "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "--nictype1", "virtio")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "--cableconnected1", "on")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "genymotion_player_version", "1")
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:11 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "genymotion_vm_name", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560")
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560")
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("startvm", "Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560", "--type", "headless")
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] "User alpitanand20@gmail.com (alpitanand20@gmail.com) logged on Hub"
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Pending calls: 0
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
Jun 2 17:23:12 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 11 - "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Jun 2 17:23:28 [Genymotion Player] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
Jun 2 17:23:28 [Genymotion Player] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
```

Comment: Did you activate with the same email id you have registered to genymotion?   What is the process you followed for installation

Comment: Just entered the email id and password for which i used to log in genymotion account

Comment: Uninstall and re-install the whole thing again ! It appears there is some problem with your license as per the log

Comment: m trying now...!!

Comment: Try with different id. Looks to be an issue with your current email id

Comment: I have the same issue with Genymotion 3.0.0 on Mac OS 10.11.6 with VirtualBox 5.2.26 (did an update without solving the problem). I have 3 virtual devices (7.0, 7.1, 9.0) which I all updated for Genymotion 3.0.0 and after this none of them start anymore. My login might be ok, but in the log I have the same error as here ("license have never been registered").

Comment: I guess it is related to Genymotion 3.0.0 in combination with Mac OS 10.11.6 (only), and I guess the threadstarter has the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping and starting the VM session directly from VirtualBox.

Comment: Oracle VM is just not opening,clicked like a hundred times

Comment: This doesn't work anyway. The VM is normally only starting when started from Genymotion, but not directly from VB.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with your email id. Uninstall the whole thing, register with a new email id, and reinstall and login with that new email id you signed up.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VirtualBox are you using? On Windows and MacOS the recommended version is 5.0.28. On Mac it is 5.0.26 (cf https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions)

Comment: And which OS do you drive?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :-D, bt windows 10